# scale_fill palette keeps getting overwritten

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, color-palette

I'm trying to follow [this seemingly excellent tutorial](http://www.r-bloggers.com/bot-botany-k-means-and-ggplot2/) on plotting k-means clusters using ggplot2, but I can't seem to keep the palette I want.

#### what I tried (working example)

Both of the below plots yield the same result:

```
test.data <- data.frame(col1=rnorm(400),col2=(rnorm(400)+5))

test.km <- kmeans(test.data,2)

test.data$cluster <- factor(test.km$cluster)
centers <- as.data.frame(test.km$centers)

ggplot(data=test.data, aes(x=col1, y=col2, color=cluster )) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set2") +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_point(data=centers, aes(x=col1,y=col2, color='Center')) +


  geom_point(data=centers, aes(x=col1,y=col2, color='Center'),
             size=52, alpha=.3, show_guide=FALSE)


ggplot(data=test.data, aes(x=col1, y=col2, color=cluster )) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set2") +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_point(data=centers, aes(x=col1,y=col2, color='Center')) +


  geom_point(data=centers, aes(x=col1,y=col2, color='Center'),
             size=52, alpha=.3, show_guide=FALSE) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set2")
```

[image: complete cluster plot]

Strangely, if I just plot the original data points with the scale fill function, the colors are changed:

```
ggplot(data=CSP.split, aes(x=CSP1, y=CSP2, color=cluster )) + 
scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set2") +
geom_point()
```

[image: partial cluster plot]

The first image looks like the default ggplot colors, i.e. evenly spaced hues around the HSL color wheel. So I think the `geom_point` series with different data are somehow overwriting the palette. I don't get any warnings, though.

Comment: colour and fill are two different aesthetics

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the right terms. In the question, "color" refers to the colors of the plotted points.

Comment: therefore you should probably use `scale_colour_brewer`

Comment: That solved it. I'd be happy to accept that as an answer if you'd like.